# How to modify the date format of date('now') in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime

When I execute the following query : `select date('now')`
It returns `2015-07-08`. But, I want to receive date in the format *mm/dd/yyyy* like *08/07/2015*. How can I do that?

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but I'm not able to figure it out for so long.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now')
```

The output would be:

08-07-2015

Comment: It should be `SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y','now')`

Comment: It would work eitherway but I guess in relation to his question you are correct.

Comment: When I am using `select * from data where expiry_date > (strftime('%m/%d/%Y', 'now') )`
it is giving me those results also which are expired. Why??